# Flutter build apk in debug mode work perfectly but in release is not the same

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, build.gradle, apk

I'm trying to build the release of my flutter android application, all works fine in debug mode (file size 80mb) but in release mode (file size 28mb) some functions don't works.

The application is installed correctly in both cases without any error.

I tried:

- flutter build apk
- flutter build apk release
- flutter build apk --split-per-abi
- flutter build apk --release --target-platform android-arm64
- modify the build.gradle

I already test all the post like that on stack overflow but I cant resolve the problem

This is the function we are talking about, it work only in debug mode but not in release

```
void applyFilter(String query) {
                if (query.isEmpty) {
                  // Se la query è vuota, mostra tutte le righe
                  setState(() {
                    tableRow();
                  });
                } else {
                  List<DataRow> filteredRows = [];

                  for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                      if (rows[i]
                              .cells[j]
                              .child
                              .toString()
                              .toLowerCase()
                              .contains(query.toLowerCase()) &&
                          selectedList.contains(j)) {
                        filteredRows.add(rows[i]);

                        break;
                      }
                    }
                  }

                  setState(() {
                    rows.clear();
                    rows.addAll(filteredRows);
                  });
                }
              }
```

All the other function works fine, this function filter data from firebase.

Comment: Can you specify which functions don't work in release mode? Perhaps a code sample as well

Comment: I edit the post with the code. Thank you